# Entity Framework 3.0 HasNoKey() for Key less table not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I am started with .NET Core 3.0 and add ASP.NET Core identity. In `tbl_SYS_AspNet_UserRoles` there is no primary key.

[image]

Then I scaffold `dbcontext` and model for another tables in database, using [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) and Entity Framework generates `e.HasNoKey()` method in model builder. I also read doc from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) .

But when I run the project and query for data `dbcontext`, I get an error:

> 'The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'tbl_SYS_AspNet_UserRoles'. Navigations can only target entity types with keys.'

**UPDATE**

I [opened an issue in github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18467) and they tag this as a bug.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to lazy load a navigation property on the model. You may be able to get around this by explicitly defining a foreign key between the 2 in model builder.

Comment: *"In tbl_SYS_AspNet_UserRoles there is no primary key."* - actually there is PK, although composite. So `HasNoKey()` does not apply to this table. If it's generated by scaffolding (reverse engineer) command, then it is a bug in that command.